# Generate a 3D grid data table

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I would like to generate a 3D Grid, not for displaying, but to do computations on it, so no draw functions I guess.

I have a simple version of what I am thinking, however, it is terribly slow:

```
generateMesh[size_, width_, distance_] := 
 Image3D@ParallelTable[
     If[#1 && #2 || #1 && #3 || #2 && #3, 1, 0] & @@ 
         (MemberQ[Range[0, width - 1], Mod[#, distance]] & /@ 
              {x, y, z}), 
     {x, 0, size}, {y, 0, size}, {z, 0, size}]
```

The `Image3D` is only to see if it is correct and not part of the speed issue. Even a call to e.g. `generateMesh[200, 2, 20]` takes about 30s or more on a laptop. This seems quite a lot for such a simple task.

Does anyone know

1. a way to improve performance?
2. know if the above code contains any typical don'ts of Mathematica programming? I guess I am evaluating things over and over again, because I am not evaluating the function passed to `Table`, but I do not know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is very fast:

```
gm2[size_, width_, distance_] :=
 Module[{f, bc = BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 3}, 3]},
  f = Join[ConstantArray[True, width], ConstantArray[False, distance - width]];
  ArrayPad[Boole@Outer[bc, f, f, f], {0, size - distance + 1}, "Periodic"]]

Timing[gm2[200, 2, 20];]
(* {0.234375, Null} *)

Image3D@gm2[20, 2, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is so fast, you can even Manipulate it:

```
Manipulate[
 Image3D@gm2[size, width, distance],
 {size, 20, 200, 1}, {width, 1, 10, 1}, {distance, 10, 20, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Previous (slower)
This one gives you a boost of at least x3

```
gm1[size_, width_, distance_] := 
 Module[{f, bc = BooleanCountingFunction[{2, 3}, 3]}, 
  f = Flatten[ Array[Join[ConstantArray[True, width], 
                          ConstantArray[False, distance - width]] &, 
                    IntegerPart[size/distance] + 1]][[;; size + 1]];
  Boole@Outer[bc, f, f, f]]

Image3D@gm1[50, 2, 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: With my computer it's boost x 16

Comment: @eldo Thanks! Good to know :)

Comment: @eldo could you check the new version?